# EFCore 2.0 - Include & ThenInclude : child collection -- grandchild collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

For a model like below

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public List<Child> GrandChildren { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild
{
    public int GrandChildId { get; set; }

    public int ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

How do I write a query that gets all the Children and GrandChildren in the Include/ThenInclude statements?

```
var record = GetAll()
 .Where(r => r.Id == 4)
 .Include(r => r.Children)
     .ThenInclude(????????????)
```

In the "ThenInclude" statement, I cannot use a select statement to get the grandchildren.  What will be the right way to get the GrandChildren collection?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just *type* the navigation property name:

```
.ThenInclude(c => c.GrandChildren)
```

It's a current Intellisense issue specifically mentioned in the [Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)
 section of the EF Core documentation:

> **Note**
>
> Current versions of Visual Studio offer incorrect code completion options and can cause correct expressions to be flagged with syntax errors when using the `ThenInclude` method after a collection navigation property. This is a symptom of an IntelliSense bug tracked at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237. It is safe to ignore these spurious syntax errors as long as the code is correct and can be compiled successfully.

Comment: This property of "GrandChilden" does not show up in the intellisense and that was the confusion for I.  With your suggestion, the code compiles fine after including the grandchildren.

Comment: I know. It's a confusion to everyone when hits it for the first time.

Comment: I confirm this with bug Visual Studio 2019. Your clarification helped me.

Comment: Note that the bug still occurs in the latest (VS 2019 16.4) release: [follow-up issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/41527). It appears, however, that it will be fixed in 16.5.

Comment: @Carsten Yes, indeed, even though EF Core people removed the above note from their documentation.